# Moving from highcharts 3.0 to 4.0: grouped column weird behavior

Tags: highcharts

I've been working on older code written for Highcharts 2.x. It was working fine with 3.0 but when moving to 4.0 we saw this weird behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/pfofo973/2/

As you can see, each period on the X axis has two stacked columns. The problem is that the first column isn't touching the X axis but has some kind of padding below it. Any idea how to correct that?

Thanks!

Here is the JS code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    "chart": {
        "renderTo": "container",
        "defaultSeriesType": "column",
        "marginTop": 100,
        "marginBottom": 20,
        "zoomType": "x",
        "spacingRight": 20
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Activity Overview"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "Grouped per week"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "tickInterval": 604800000,
        "tickWidth": 0,
        "maxZoom": 1209600000,
        "x": -30,
        "labels": {}
    },
    "yAxis": [
        {
            "title": {
                "text": "Days"
            },
            "endOnTick": false,
            "maxPadding": 1,
            "categories": [],
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "maxPadding": 1,
            "categories": [],
            "title": {
                "text": "Number",
                "style": {
                    "color": "#AA4643"
                }
            },
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "color": "#AA4643"
                }
            },
            "opposite": true,
            "index": 1
        },
        {
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "maxPadding": 0.8,
            "endOnTick": false,
            "lineWidth": 0,
            "categories": [],
            "opposite": true,
            "tickLength": 0,
            "max": 300,
            "title": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "labels": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "index": 2
        },
        {
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "endOnTick": false,
            "minPadding": 6,
            "maxPadding": 0.5,
            "lineWidth": 0,
            "opposite": true,
            "tickLength": 0,
            "max": 100,
            "min": 50,
            "categories": [],
            "title": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "labels": {
                "text": ""
            },
            "index": 3
        }
    ],
    "legend": {
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "y": 40,
        "floating": true,
        "borderWidth": 0
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "crosshairs": true,
        "useHTML": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "normal"
        },
        "spline": {
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "dashStyle": "ShortDot",
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false,
                "states": {
                    "hover": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "radius": 4
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "stack": "survey",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    7.3
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    8.2
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    7.8
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    8.9
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    6.7
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    8
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    8.4
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    6.5
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    6.6
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    4.9
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    1.8
                ]
            ],
            "_colorIndex": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "R1",
            "stack": "survey",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    4.2
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    3.9
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    3.9
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    5.3
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    3.2
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    4.4
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    3.1
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    2.8
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    2.8
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    2.2
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    0.9
                ]
            ],
            "_colorIndex": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "A1",
            "stack": "survey",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    1.8
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    1.7
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    1.5
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    0.9
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    1.7
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    1.3
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    1.3
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    1.9
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    1.2
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    1.2
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    0.4
                ]
            ],
            "_colorIndex": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "Nb R",
            "type": "spline",
            "color": "#AA4643",
            "yAxis": 1,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    3.7
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    3.8
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    4.1
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    4.1
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    3.6
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    3.8
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    3.8
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    3.5
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    3.8
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    3.3
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    3.1
                ]
            ],
            "_symbolIndex": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "P",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#64E572",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    34.55
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    23.84
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    38.58
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    27.78
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    34.07
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    33.75
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    38.71
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    38.07
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    31.35
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    27.95
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    30
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "S",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#508432",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    49.09
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    49.01
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    44.67
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    50.56
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    49.12
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    51.25
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    46.08
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    42.64
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    51.89
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    56.52
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    61.67
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Su",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#058DC7",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    3.64
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    4.64
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    1.52
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    7.22
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    3.98
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    3.75
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    0.92
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    3.55
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    3.24
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    2.48
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    3.33
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "F",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#24CBE5",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    6.36
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    10.6
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    8.63
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    6.11
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    3.54
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    3.13
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    4.15
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    5.08
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    3.24
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    6.83
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    1.67
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Pr",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#DDDF00",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    4.64
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    0.88
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    3.13
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    2.3
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Cl",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#ED5618",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    2.22
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    0.44
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    0.63
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    0.92
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    2.03
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    1.08
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    null
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    null
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Other",
            "stack": "rater",
            "stacking": "percent",
            "color": "#FF9655",
            "yAxis": 2,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    6.36
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    7.28
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    4.57
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    6.11
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    7.96
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    4.38
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    6.91
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    8.63
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    9.19
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    4.97
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    3.33
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "line",
            "name": "QoH",
            "yAxis": 3,
            "data": [
                [
                    1406444400000,
                    96.5
                ],
                [
                    1407049200000,
                    96.2
                ],
                [
                    1407654000000,
                    94.7
                ],
                [
                    1408258800000,
                    95.9
                ],
                [
                    1408863600000,
                    95.1
                ],
                [
                    1409468400000,
                    95.3
                ],
                [
                    1410073200000,
                    96.3
                ],
                [
                    1410678000000,
                    94.4
                ],
                [
                    1411282800000,
                    96.6
                ],
                [
                    1411887600000,
                    96.8
                ],
                [
                    1412492400000,
                    98.1
                ]
            ],
            "_colorIndex": 3,
            "_symbolIndex": 1
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: looks good in the fiddle. no padding can be seen

Comment: same here, using latest FF.

Comment: jsfiddle link was wrong. I have updated it with the correct one

Comment: Just tested your fiddle in 3.x version, and it works exactly the same way, see: http://jsfiddle.net/pfofo973/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because left y axis has 0 at that level.
To fix it you can set

```
startOnTick: false,
min: 0.5
```

for that axis.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pfofo973/4/